# camel http4 route in thread with timeout

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'd like to use http4 route, but have it execute inside a thread with a timeout. I already have my http4 route setup, something like this:

```
from("direct:start")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,simple("format=json&count=${in.headers.count}"))
.to("http4://www.host.com/someapi")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.JACKSON,MyResponseType.class)
.to("bean:SomeBean?method=echo");
```

I'd like to apply a 100ms timeout around the http call, and route to a failure handler in that case. Does anyone know how that can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a 100ms timeout on the client by specifying `http4://foo?httpClient.soTimeout=100`. When a timeout occurs it will probably throw an exception that you can handle like so (off the top of my head, untested code):

```
onException(IOException.class).to("direct:timeouts");

from("direct:start")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,simple("format=json&count=${in.headers.count}"))
.to("http4://www.host.com/someapi?httpClient.soTimeout=100")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.JACKSON,MyResponseType.class)
.to("bean:SomeBean?method=echo");

from("direct:timeouts").to("...");
```

Comment: This isn't exactly ideal, because the soTimeout maps to the socket's read timeout. So it doesn't take into consideration the connect time, and the timeout is reset for every socket.read() that happens. So if I have a strict latency that I need to enforce, soTimeout can't guarantee that. When doing this without camel, the only way I know of is to execute the HttpClient inside a thread and enforce the timeout from the outside (via a Future with a timeout on Future.get()).

Comment: But I will get you +1 for showing me the onException trick. How do I make sure that only exceptions from a particular route get directed to the onException route though?

Comment: Are your latency requirements that strict? Thinking out loud you might be able to implement your use case by executing the HTTP call on a [SEDA](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) queue with a timeout.

Comment: Concerning onException you can make it "route specific", see [here](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) and scroll to _Using global and per route exception clauses_.

Comment: My concern with SEDA queue is that I don't want anything to get queued (or specifically I don't want it to block). It should always dispatch directly to a thread. I suppose I can get around that by choosing an appropriate number of threads for SEDA thread pool(?).

Answer (score 0):

The recipient list EIP has timeout support
http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Answer (score 0):

An update... I think the syntax for the timeout configurations has changed in later versions of Camel. With Camel 2.16.2 I found that the timeout parameters in the documentation can be set via query param options, but they need to be prefixed with **httpClient.** . Here is what worked for me:

```
?httpClient.connectTimeout=10000&httpClient.connectionRequestTimeout=10000&httpClient.socketTimeout=30000
```

I verified by testing with ridiculously small values (1 ms) and it produced "read timed out" errors.

It looks the availble options for httpClient are the setter values on [RequestConfig.Builder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html).